# Why I can't see icon images on UWP?

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms, following this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/):

```
public MasterPage()
{
    var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();
    masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
    {
        Title = "Contacts",
        IconSource = "contacts.png",
        TargetType = typeof(Pages.Contacts)
    });
    masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
    {
        Title = "ToDo",
        IconSource = "todo.png",
        TargetType = typeof(Pages.ToDo)
    });
    masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
    {
        Title = "Reminders",
        IconSource = "reminders.png",
        TargetType = typeof(Pages.Reminder)
    });
    masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
    {
        Title = "Login",
        IconSource = "reminders.png",
        TargetType = typeof(Pages.Login)
    });
    masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
    {
        Title = "Sign Up",
        IconSource = "reminders.png",
        TargetType = typeof(Pages.SignUp)
    });

    listView = new ListView
    {
        ItemsSource = masterPageItems,
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
            var imageCell = new ImageCell();
            imageCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Title");
            imageCell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "IconSource");
            return imageCell;
        }),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None
    };

    Padding = new Thickness(0, 40, 0, 0);
    Icon = "hamburger.png";
    Title = "Personal Organiser";
    Content = new StackLayout
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Children = {
        listView
    }
    };
}
```

I've place all the icons.png (todo, reminders, and so on) within the MyProject.UWP root.

But when I run it from Visual Studio (debug mode, x64) I just can't see the icons within Master-Detail Page's navigation layout.

EDIT: I can't see `BuildAction` field on the image's Properties:

[image]

EDIT 2: Now I See. You need to "Add Existing Item", not place copy/paste image on the folder.

Comment: Assets aren't loaded relative to the project files. They are loaded relative to the executable image. The executable image doesn't know, that it was built from an arbitrary project layout.

Comment: I mean `IconSource`. They shouldn't be in the Assets folder, right? On the root...

Comment: Do you see them on other platforms? Have you set BuildAction as Content in UWP?

Comment: Try resize the window of the uwp app.

Comment: As @YuriS said you should set image source `BuildAction` as Content within uwp. For more, please refer to [Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images).

Comment: you can place (copy/paste) into the folder, and then Include them into the project (in the right click context menu).

Comment: @YuriS: add the answer, and you get "Accepted" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BuildAction should be set to Content

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding all the icons to the root project of UWP and set the build action property as content....